# Azure Devops API to get all files in a repository with folders

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-devops

Is there an API endpoint for Azure Devops where I can get all leaf nodes (anything that isn't a folder essentially) for a tree structure? Right now, I loop through the root of the repository, then for recurse over each folder, then each folder within the folder, etc. There isn't really a better way to do it unless there is an API that will return the contents of a repository as a list that I can then filter based on `gitObjectType`.

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0&tabs=HTTP#single-level-of-recursion) endpoint, but when I specify the root of my repository, it only returns one item.

Again, here is a representation of what my repo looks like:

```
repo root
    -> Folder1
        -> File1
        -> File 2
    -> Folder 2
        -> Folder 3
            -> File 3
        -> File 4
    -> File 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an API endpoint for Azure Devops where I can get all leaf nodes (anything that isn't a folder essentially) for a tree structure?

To get all files of a repo, you can use the following Rest API to get the tree of the repo: [Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP).

You can set the parameter:`recursionLevel=Full` in the Rest API URL and remove the specified path.

For example:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?recursionLevel=Full&api-version=5.1
```

It will return all files and gitObjectType.

[image]

Comment: I tried this endpoint, but I had an extra parameter, so my url looked like `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?recursionLevel=Full&$format=text&api-version=5.1` - when I removed the `&$format=text` parameter, it worked beautifully! This is a much cleaner solution than what I have currently, thank you!